# Java RequestDispatcher redirecting not working

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I am trying to redirect page from servlet using RequestDispatcher but it is not working. My code for servlet is this:

```
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
List<User> users = new LinkedList<User>();

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public LoginServlet() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    super();
    File file = new File("C:/Users/Misel/workspace/SalonNamestaja/src/org/SalonNamestaja/dataFiles/users.txt");
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    String line;
    String[] parts;

    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        parts = line.split("\\|");
        users.add(new User(parts[1], parts[2], parts[0], parts[4], parts[3], parts[5], parts[6]));
    }
    fileReader.close();
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/text");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    String json = request.getParameter("jsonData");

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    User user = mapper.readValue(json, User.class);
    //System.out.println(user.getName() + user.getPassword() + " | " + user.getLevel());

    if(user.getLevel().equals("korisnik")) {
        user = new LoginService().authenticate(users, user.getName(), user.getPassword());
        //System.out.println("Postoji korisnik");
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("activeUser", user);

        //response.getWriter().write("true");

        RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/dashboard.jsp");
        requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
        //System.out.println("OK");
        return;
    }else if(user.getLevel().equals("admin")) { 
        user = new LoginService().authenticate_admin(users, user.getName(), user.getPassword());
        System.out.println("Postoji admin");
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("activeUser", user);

        response.getWriter().write("true");
        return;
    }else {
        System.out.println("Korisnik ne postoji!");
        response.getWriter().write("false");
    }
}
```

I tried to redirect with sendRedirect() and this didn't work too. I can't find where is the problem, so if can somebody help me.

Comment: Explain `not working`.

Comment: Not redirecting to another page (dashboard.jsp)

Comment: That's kinda obvious but if that's all the info you can provide on how your app's behaving, I don't think you'll get much help here. Good luck!

Comment: No errors, everything works except redirecting

Comment: Well what do you get when doPost executes?

Comment: It stays on the same page, it checks if user exists and stay on same page, not redirecting.

Comment: Then your logic is wrong. Also, use `sendRedirect` to redirect.